# Closed iOS app to wake up on BLE

Tags: ios

We're developing an iOS app that is registered to run in the background as well.
This app gets data from our BLE device. all is working OK until the user decides to close the app (Swipe it a way from the "Recent apps" list).
From there on, The BLE device data does not "wake" up our app.
I know this is a shot in the dark, but if anyone knows about a solution or a workaround, that would be great.
Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to awake your phone. If your app comes under the region of beacon then,

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
```

above method gets called automatically. So you need to put some local notification like "You are near to beacon zone" to awake the phone. But you must reenter into the region.

Once your app enter in the region write following code to restart the beacon process,

```
[self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [[UIApplication  sharedApplication] 
                                      beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
      NSLog(@"End of tolerate time. Application should be suspended now if we do not ask more 'tolerance'");
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:UIBackgroundTaskInvalid];
}];

if (bgTask == UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
{
     NSLog(@"This application does not support background mode");
} else {
     //if application supports background mode, we'll see this log.
     NSLog(@"Application will continue to run in background");
}
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: I was actually talking about a BLE (Non iBeacon) device. I now understand that this is doable only in iBeacon.

Comment: Ok. Just for confirmation, have you declare Core Bluetooth background execution mode in `info.plist` in your project? Apple documentation says if you declare that, 'the system wakes it up from a suspended state to allow it to handle Bluetooth-related events'.

Comment: Yes. background and suspend are working just fine. I was asking about a terminated app. I got a formal answer from Apple

Comment: The user swiping away an app is a clear signal to iOS that they no longer want this app running. Once this happens, iOS will respect the users wishes and will not "wake" your app until the user manually relaunches it first.
It is not possible for you to guess the users intentions; whether they did this by mistake, misguided attempt to save battery, or they really did not want your app to run in the background anymore. So, even if you were to find a workaround, by keeping on relaunching your app despite the users wishes is a sure way to get your app deleted, and worse trigger a negative review.